# Explicit definition from recursive definition

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the recursive definition:
$$a_0=0,~a_{n+1} = 28 + a_n + \left\lfloor\frac{a_n}{16}\right\rfloor$$
I want to create an explicit form for that. I was able to transform the problem into finding an explicit form of
$$b_0 = 0, b_n = 28 - \left\lfloor\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n- 1} b_i}{16}\right\rfloor$$
as
$$a_n = \sum_{i=0}^n b_i$$
, which might lead to an easier case. Any ideas how to progress from here?